# SQL Server - Get Distinct Ids from 2 column and store in one coulmn table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, query-optimization

I have the following table

```
user_one    user_two
20151844    2016000
20151844    2017000
2018000     20151844
20151844    20151025
20151036    20151844
```

Generated by the following query

```
 select * from [dbo].[Contact] C
 where C.user_one=20151844 or C.user_two=20151844
```

I want to get the following result excluding the current user Id **20151844**

```
contact_Ids
2016000
2017000
2018000
20151025
20151036
```

What is the best optimized way to accomplish it? knowing that i want to join the ids to get the contact name form the user table.

Here's my tables:

```
Contact 
user_one (int FK User.user_id), user_two (int FK User.user_id), status, action_user (int)

User
user_id (int PK), name , ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `UNION` and `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT c.[contact_Ids],
       u.[name]
       FROM (SELECT [user_one] [contact_Ids]
                    FROM [Contact]
                    WHERE [user_one] <> 20151844
                          AND [user_two] = 20151844
             UNION
             SELECT [user_two] [contact_Ids]
                    FROM [Contact]
                    WHERE [user_two] <> 20151844
                          AND [user_one] = 20151844) c
             INNER JOIN [User] u
                        ON u.[user_id] = c.[contact_Ids]
       ORDER BY c.[contact_Ids];
```

Answer (score 2):

another option: `iif`

```
select iif(C.user_one=20151844,C.user_two,C.user_one) as contact_IDs
from [dbo].[Contact] C
where C.user_one=20151844 or C.user_two=20151844
```

Comment: works fine,  but i need to ask if the option iff would it be faster to retreive them by union, knowing that i added an inner join to your query

Comment: select U.first_name from [dbo].[User] U
    inner join 
    (
    select iif(C.user_one=20151844,C.user_two,C.user_one) as contact_IDs
    from [dbo].[Contact] C
    where( C.user_one=20151844 or C.user_two=20151844 )and C.[status] = '1'
    ) C on C.contact_IDs = U.user_id

Comment: `iif` is a shortcut for a `CASE WHEN` statement, so there is no performance hit either way. The real speed would be if the columns are indexed

Answer (score 0):

Use `apply` :

```
select tt.contact_Ids
from table t cross apply ( 
         values (user_one), (user_two) 
    ) tt (contact_Ids)
group by tt.contact_Ids
having count(*) = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Set operations `Union` and `except` works the best.

```
;with ids as (
select user_one id from contact
union
select user_two from contact
except
select 20151844
)
select u.*
from [user] u 
inner join ids on u.user_id = ids.id
```